# I sent money to a bitcoin wallet from Blizzcoin and there's nothing there?

Tags: buy-bitcoins

Using blizzcoin.com I sent bitcoins to the address I have for the bitcoin wallet client, and it took forever to sync the blocks. Once it had finished I was expecting to see the money there, but saw nothing.  Can anyone explain or tell me how to resolve this?

Comment: Can you tell us what address you sent the coins to?

Comment: The coins have not been sent yet. You can check it out on [blockexplorer](http://blockexplorer.com/address/15AsgvDDtbwq2d2pT7gNpapedBrk2JQzxU).

Comment: Thank you. I can't seem to find an email address to ask if blizzcoin has sent them :(

Comment: [blockchain.info](http://blockchain.info/address/15AsgvDDtbwq2d2pT7gNpapedBrk2JQzxU) would show if a transaction had been sent but was waiting for confirmations.  It shows nothing, so blizzcoin probably didn't send anything.  I've never heard of blizzcoin before.  Is it possible you were ripped off?

Comment: Looks like it arrived.

Comment: It's possible OP used the same address elsewhere.

Answer (score 6):

According to [blockchain.info](http://blockchain.info/address/15AsgvDDtbwq2d2pT7gNpapedBrk2JQzxU) the coins weren't sent yet.

Here's [a post from another blizzcoin customer](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=74457.msg825763#msg825763) saying that it took 2 days for his purchased coins to be sent:

> apparently because I Manually transferred money to them instead of ordering through their web interface, it wasn't an instant transfer of bitcoins.

Could that be your problem too?  How long has it been since you sent the money to them?